# Matlab function convertion to R

Tags: r, matlab, function, operators

i'm trying to convert a code from MATLAB to R and find a difficulty in a otherwise easy convertion.

```
function [X1, X2, X3, X4] = example (A, B, C, D, E)

SOME STATEMENTS

END
```

cant find how to input in my r code the *X1,...,X4*. My code is the following

```
example <- function(A, B, C, D, E){

SOME STATEMENTS

}
```

How and where to insert the Xi's?

Also how to convert the MATLAB statement `=%` in R?

```
fprintf('A=%D, B=%E, C=%F,', A, B, C)
```

Comment: `=%` is not a command in MATLAB; `%` normally starts a comment for the rest of the line, making that statement error (Unless you put it inside a string, but it's impossible to tell you more if you don't show us context)

Comment: Just edited and insert more informations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `R`, you can put `list(X1, X2, X3, X4)` to the end of your function block. When you call the function `example(A,B,C,D,D)`, the output will be in the format of list, i.e., `list(X1, X2, X3, X4)`

```
example <- function(A, B, C, D, E){

SOME STATEMENTS

list(X1, X2, X3, X4)
}
```